# tensorflow NameError: name 'eval_input_fn' is not defined

Tags: tensorflow

I am following tensorflow's [getting started](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started). I downloaded and installed anaconda today. when run, the program below produces:

```
  File "p3.py", line 35, in <module>
    eval_loss = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
NameError: name 'eval_input_fn' is not defined

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
# Declare list of features, we only have one real-valued feature
def model(features, labels, mode):
  # Build a linear model and predict values
  W = tf.get_variable("W", [1], dtype=tf.float64)
  b = tf.get_variable("b", [1], dtype=tf.float64)
  y = W*features['x'] + b
  # Loss sub-graph
  loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - labels))
  # Training sub-graph
  global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
  train = tf.group(optimizer.minimize(loss),
                   tf.assign_add(global_step, 1))
  # ModelFnOps connects subgraphs we built to the
  # appropriate functionality.
  return tf.contrib.learn.ModelFnOps(
      mode=mode, predictions=y,
      loss=loss,
      train_op=train)

estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=model)
# define our data sets
x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y_train = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x": x_train}, y_train, 4, num_epochs=1000)

# train
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
# Here we evaluate how well our model did. 
train_loss = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)
eval_loss = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)  #line 35  
print("train loss: %r"% train_loss)
print("eval loss: %r"% eval_loss)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you haven't copy-pasted the definition of the evaluation input function.
You can find it directly in the tutorial you linked.

Here's the line

```
eval_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x":x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)
```